# Tfs not working on hosting application to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

***strong text***On localhost i am able to login to TFS with the help of that i am generating list.
But when i am deploying this code to IIS it is not asking for the credentials as no dialog box for credential it is asking  and i am unable to generate list.

Is it possible to host TFS application TO IIS?
I

Comment: Please add a little more detail on what you're doing. It looks like you may be trying to generate some kind of report or for on top of data in TFS and you're expecting IIS to handle the impersonation for you to connect to TFS. It's unclear how you've configured IIS to authenticate... It's unclear how you are passing the credential to TFS. It's unclear what services on TFS you're calling. Are they REST calls? SOAP calls? Are you using the TFS Client Object Model?

Comment: From a license perspective, be sure to read the Visual Studio and TFS license whitepaper. If you're impersonating your users to TFS, each of these users needs a TFS CAL. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350

Comment: @jessehouwing Please check the screenshot.

Comment: Iis is probably configured to allow anonymous access and isn't configured for Windows auth.

Comment: @jessehouwing But while giving my credentials in application pools i am able to generate list..But it's not good to give my credentials..so for that i used popup thing to give his/her credentials

Comment: Yeah so enable Windows auth on the virtual directory/site and configure asp.net to apply impersonation from the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

To configure ASP.NET to impersonate the Windows identity supplied by IIS as the WindowsIdentity for the ASP.NET application, edit the Web.config file for the application and set the **impersonate** attribute of the **identity** configuration element to **true**, as shown in the following example.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```